# The reason why UnboundLocalError is caused with yield of variable of global scope in Python

Tags: python-3.x

The following code generates the error on title of this mail.

```
n=2
def func():
    while True:
        y=n**2
        n=y
        yield y

print(next(iter(func())))
```

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment`

However, when I changed to the following code, the code works expectedly.

```
n=2
def func():
    while True:
        y=globals()['n']**2
        globals()['n']=y
        yield y

print(next(iter(func())))
```

I don't know why first code generates error.
Please tell me the reason why first code generates error.

Comment: Can you put your code in "code-blocks"? You do this by putting ` around your code like this : ` hello ` .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Your issue is with your scoping of the variable `n`. Since you are declaring `n` outside of the scope of `func()`, that method does not know about the variable. If you changed your original block to be as follows:

**NOTE** `func()`, as written, is an infinite loop, and yielding will result in an infinite generator. To prevent this, some breaking condition is needed.

```
def func():
    n = 2
    while True:
    y=n**2
    n=y
    yield y
```

And then consume the generator created by the `yield` statement as follows:

```
for item in func():
    print(item, "\n")
```

You should then see the results you expect!

The version I've provided works because now the variable `n` is "in scope" of the method `func()` and therefore does not need to be global.

A different alternative, if `n` must be outside `func()` is to make it a parameter.

```
n = 2
def func(n):
    while True:
        y = n**2
        n = y
        yield y
```

And a third solution, preventing the infinite loop in the generator:

```
n = 2
def func(n):
    # Define y for break to work initially
    y = 0
    while y <=  10000: # Replace 10000 with your ceiling value
        y = n**2
        n = y
        yield y
```

And then consume with the same for loop provided earlier.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your code causes infinite loop. I expect to get the needed value only when the next for generator is called. Do you have the other idea?

Comment: You can limit the iterations using `range()` when consuming the generator. Your function itself is an infinite loop, and a generator can be consumed only once. If you were to add a terminating factor to your function, then when you reach that terminating condition, the generator will be considered "consumed". This will prevent any infinite loops. If you need an example of `range` let me know, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to see your example of range. Please update your example.

Comment: I was mistaken, `range` will not work in the for loop. Instead, you'll need to provide a break condition inside your function (added an example to the answer) or in the loop where you are consuming the generator.

Comment: I understood that generator may be not able to refer  outer global variable. Is my understanding correct? Please tell me your comment.

Comment: Is this Python's bug?

Comment: It is not a bug in Python. I addressed the issue of variable scoping in my answer. I have also provided several ways to get a working version going. I suggest experimenting with the code snippets I've given you and rethinking your design.

Comment: I have found the resolution. As you said, this is not bug of Python. The following code is my expected code.

Comment: I found the resolution of this issue. This is not Python's bug.
inline`
    n = 2
    while True:
        y=n**2
        n=y
        yield y
it = iter(func())
print(next(it))
print(next(it))`

Comment: Be sure to post that as an answer, for others that find their way to this page! That code is the equivalent of the `for` loop I posted, but uses an iterator instead. Nice solution, and glad you were able to figure it out!